# FANNY and K-means clustering with r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Why the clusters assigned with k-means are sometimes different with respect to fanny?

```
## Data

mtcars[2:7]

# Code

k3<-kmeans(mtcars[2:7],3)

mtcars$clusterkmeans<-k3$cluster

g3<-fanny(mtcars[2:7],memb.exp = 1.2,k=3)

mtcars$clusterfanny<-g3$clustering

## Result
print(mtcars)
```

Comment: K-means starts with random centers and is non deterministic.  Meaning the the results maybe different on each run.  I can’t comment on the fanny function.